# PHP - while loop loading

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a while loop, that takes ip's and passwords from a text file and logins to some servers that I rent using HTTP Auth.

```
<?php

$username = 'admin';


function login($server, $login){

global $username, $password, $server;

$options = array(

    CURLOPT_URL => $server,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("
    Host: {$server}
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Connection: keep-alive
    Authorization: Basic {$login}

"));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $http_status == 200 ) {
 //do something  
echo "Completed";

} 
else { echo "Something went wrong";}

};

$file = fopen('myServers.txt', 'r');


while (! feof($file)) {
$m = explode(fgets($file), ':');
$password = $m[0];
$server = $m[1];
$login = base64_encode("{$username}:{$password}");
login($server, $login);
};




?>
```

The script works fine. However, when I load the page on my localhost, it takes forever to load and then prints out everything at once when its done with the entire file.

I want to print out `Something went wrong` or `completed` each time it does the file, I don't want it to wait for the entire file to go through the loop.

Comment: Can you just `echo` something from within the while loop?

Comment: As @rar , suggested, you can `echo` out something as you are looping through the items. If you want to interact with the page while it is parsing these items, your only option would be to load the page, then make an `ajax` call to parse the items

Comment: The problem is that the web server finishes the script completely before sending the entire output to the client. That's just the way it works. If you want interactive, or at least periodic response, use AJAX.

Comment: If I echo within the while statement, nothing is changing. Still loading the entire file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably going to want to take a look at PHP flushing, which pushes content to the browser before continuing on with creating more page content. Note that from what I remember of PHP, you need to ob_flush() and flush() at the same time in order to properly flush content to the browser.

https://www.php.net/flush

[Edit]

Example: You might try changing your echo statements to something resembling the below:

```
echo "Completed";
ob_flush();
flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether you can do what you want to do depends on the web server being used, and how it's configured, with regards to **output buffering**.

A good place to start reading would be the documentation for PHP's [`flush`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) function.

A call to `flush` is intended to push output to the end user - but sometimes the web server implements it's own output buffering, which defeats the effect.

From the `flush` documentation:

> Several servers, especially on Win32, will still buffer the output from your script until it terminates before transmitting the results to the browser.